# How to show the status of an internet connection?

Tags: c#, wpf

I was wondering how one would go about showing the status of the internet connecting in WPF C#?

What I want to do is that if a connection is available, a circular textbox would show the color green else red. I already have the circular textbox in place. I am confused about how the code would be able to keep checking for a connection? Right now it just checks on compile time and that's it. I am still trying to learn how all this works, so any suggestion in terms of how this could be done differently would be highly appreciated!

Edit: My code currently looks like this.

```
public LoginWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     username.Focus();

     NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged;
     var isAvailable = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
     OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(isAvailable);
}

public void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(bool isAvailable)
{
    if (isAvailable == true)
    {
        wifiAvailability.Background = Brushes.LightGreen;
    }
    else
    {
        wifiAvailability.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
}

public void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(object obj, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs eventArgs)
{
        OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(eventArgs.IsAvailable);
}
```

Edit: The exception is "System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".

Depending on whether or not an internet connection is available, the exception happens inside the if-statement of the `public void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(bool isAvailable)` method.

Comment: Uh, I don't think that's checking at compile time. I guess you're just calling this method once on startup? Perhaps you should use a Timer instead.

Comment: Maybe the event is being executed on a different thread than the UI thread. Are you sure the code is being executed on the correct thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged`. It fires everytime network status changes, so there is no need for timers or tasks.

```
NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += (obj, eventArgs) =>
{
    if (eventArgs.IsAvailable)
    {
        // Change color to available
        return;
    }

    //Change color to unavailable
};
```

If you want to keep it cleaner you can move it to a separate method.

```
NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += NetworkAvailabilityChanged;

public void NetworkAvailabilityChanged(object obj, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs eventArgs) {}
```

Edit:

It won't fire immediately, because it only fires on change. If you want to immediately check for network you can expand this, for example like this:

```
public YourConstructor()
{   
    NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged;
    var isAvailable = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
    OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(isAvailable);
}

public void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(bool isAvailable)
{
    if (isAvailable)
    {
        //
    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
}

public void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(object obj, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(eventArgs.IsAvailable);
}
```

Edit2:
I don't have this issue, but `NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged` is called from another thread. You can update `UI` *only* on `UI` thread. In order to achieve this you have to call dispatcher to invoke your code on `UI` thread, like this:

```
public void OnNetworkAvailabilityChanged(bool isAvailable)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        if (isAvailable)
        {
            // Change color to available
            return;
        }

        //Change color to unavailable
    });
}
```

Comment: Would I place the NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += NetworkAvailabilityChanged part in the constructor? I am a little unsure in terms of how this should be implemented. I haven't worked much with events.

Comment: Yes, you can put it in the place from where it should start listening for change. It is not going to be disposed until you either unsubscribe with `NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged -= NetworkAvailabilityChanged` or close the program.

Comment: I placed it in the constructor as I guess that would make sense so that it starts listening right away when running the program, however, nothing really happens on start-up. If I change my internet connection I get this error "System.InvalidOperationException".

Comment: Please update your question with the code you currently have.

Comment: If you want to check for this immediately, you have to modify the code a little bit. I provided an example.

Comment: It now immediately checks for the internet connection, however, when I change my connection, I get the same error as before: System.InvalidOperationException... :(

Answer (score -1):

You can implement this trusted code.

If you need it to check redundantly you can call it in a thread that executes every n sec or min :

```
private bool CheckConnection(String URL)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.Timeout = 5000;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can replace `if` with simple `return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;`

Comment: Sure you can return what you need.

Comment: This checks the connection to a specific web resource, not the general network availability.